# Log number of queued requests OWIN self-hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I do have my OWIN application hosted as a Windows Service and I am getting a lot of timeout issues from different clients. I have some metrics in place around the request/response time however the numbers are very different. For example I can see the client is taking around one minute to perform a request that looks like in the server is taking 3-4 seconds. I am then assuming that the number of requests that can be accepted has reached the limit and subsequent requests that come in would get queued up. Am I right? If that's the case, is there any way I can monitor the number of incoming requests at a given time and how big is the queue (as in number of requests pending to get served)?

I am playing around with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.host.httplistener.owinhttplistener.setrequestprocessinglimits(v=vs.113).aspx but doesn't look to have any effect.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpListener is built on top of Http.Sys so you need to use its performance counters and ETW traces to get this level of information.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2007/01/18/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-1-capturing-a-trace.aspx

Comment: I ended up comparing the default variable values for the HttpListener in the OWIN source code and the values I have configured and that made a massive difference.